# Find the previous Row with a specific value at in column A

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

[image: Sample sheet with and without formulae]

Given the above sample sheet, which has semantic 'header', 'subheader' and 'subtotal' rows, I am trying to determine a formula to locate the previous subheader row relative the current cell.  For example, if the formula were entered in `F5`, it would locate row `2` and, if entered into `F17`, it would locate row `13`.

The rows are conditionally formatted as a header, subheader or subtotal, by the existence of values `H`, `S` or `T` in column `$A:$A`, i.e subheader row `n` is a row where `$An = "S"`.  Now, I would like to extend this concept to my formulae.

A header row will always be followed by a subheader (so I do not to have to worry about headers and subheaders that are out of order).

I have tried the following:

1. `=MATCH("S", OFFSET($A5, 0, 0, -ROW($A5), 1), 0)`

   This always returns row `2`, because `MATCH` returns the *first* match, in the set, and I can't limit the `OFFSET` height (i.e. recursively, because the previous subheader location is unknown);
2. `{=LARGE(MATCH("S", OFFSET($A5, 0, 0, -ROW($A5), 1), 0), 1)}`

   This also returns `2`, because, even in array context (i.e. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>), `MATCH` still just returns the first result;
3. `=LARGE(IF(OFFSET($A5, 0, 0, -ROW($A5), 1)="S", ROW(OFFSET($A5, 0, 0, -ROW($A5), 1))), 1)`

   This returns `0`, because `IF` is not expecting an array here, so expands `OFFSET($A5, 0, 0, -ROW($A5), 1)` to a single value `0`, which does not match `"S"`, and `LARGE` treats `FALSE` as a number;
4. `{=LARGE(IF(OFFSET($A5, 0, 0, -ROW($A5), 1)="S", ROW(OFFSET($A5, 0, 0, -ROW($A5), 1))), 1)}`

   This returns `#VALUE`, because array expansion occurs too early, which leaves `-ROW($A5)` as array `-{5}`, which is not a valid numeric `height` parameter to `OFFSET` (I wanted the `IF(OFFSET(...)="S",...)` bit to be an array, not the `-ROW($A5)` bit, but Excel cannot distinguish).

I am currently targeting Excel 2010.  Earlier versions are not applicable (although forward-compatibility is a bonus).  I am trying to avoid VBA, since it is more difficult for me to distribute *.xlsm files than *.xlsx (besides, I already know how to do it with VBA).

Are there any other things I can try?

Comment: This is possibly the **most detailed question** I have seen come across the Excel tag on SuperUser or StackOverflow in the last couple months.  Thank you for your effort in documenting what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to cheat and use a mixed absolute/relative formula.  This is an array formula (enter with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) entered into cell `B4` but it could go anywhere in row 4.  It will return the row number of the one marked `S`.

```
=MAX(IF($A$1:A4="S",ROW($A$1:A4)))
```

When copied down, the second part of the reference `B4 and A4` will increase.  This ensures that you get the row with the largest match that is **above** the current row.  You can enter those formulas more quickly using <kbd>F4</kbd> after typing/selecting the relevant range.  This will cycle the dollar signs through all the choices.

**Picture of ranges**

[image: picture of data and result]

**Used to replace your formulas**

After reading the question a bit (and based on the edit by @SteveTaylor), it seems your use for this is to update your formulas.  You can use the row that is returned from above along with `INDEX` to get ranges of data to sum.  I see 2 formulas that can be replaced:

- Total calculation for each labeled row of data.  In this case, the subtotal row above can be referenced dynamically.
- Total calcualtion for the substotal row.  In this case the values to sum from above can be reference dynamically.

For the single row data, you can use the formula, starting in `F3` as an array formula.  Note that I switched over to using `SUMPRODUCT` which makes it much easier to go to more than 2 columns.

```
=C3*SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(D:E,MAX(IF($A$1:A3="S",ROW($A$1:A3))),),D3:E3)
```

For the total row formula, you can use, starting in `F11`, again array formula:

```
=SUM(F10:INDEX($F$1:F10, 1+MAX(IF($A$1:A11="S",ROW($A$1:A11)))))
```

If you want one formula to rule them all! then you can combine these into a nested `IF` based on the value in column `A`.  Here is said array formula, starting in `F2` which can be copied down.

```
=IF(
  A2="S", 
  SUM(D2:E2), 
    IF(A2="T", 
      SUM(F1:INDEX($F$1:F1, 1+MAX(IF($A$1:A2="S",ROW($A$1:A2))))), 
      C2*SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(D:E,MAX(IF($A$1:A2="S",ROW($A$1:A2))),),D2:E2)))
```

This formula does not differentiate between a blank row and a "data" row.  It currently returns 0 for the spacer row which is fine.

**Picture of results of and formulas** for two blocks of your data.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @SteveTaylor, thanks for the edit.  It pointed out that OP might want to see the row in his formulas.  I incorporated those changes but used dynamic ranges with `INDEX` instead of `INDIRECT`.

Comment: That...is perfect.  And so obvious once I'd read it, that I'm kicking myself for not having worked out the original array formula on my own!  I did, at least, work out how to incorporate into my own formulae, but didn't go as far as *one rule to rule column F* -- I might try that later!!

Comment: Incidentally, I've never seen `INDEX` used in that fashion (as part of a reference), only as a value.  I must look into that more, it might be more appropriate than some of my usual calls to `OFFSET`...