# Excel 2010 - Max Value in Column based on Cell Row Position

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on a spreadsheet that requires all populated rows to have an ID (minus the headers). Normally, simply doing "=PreviousCell.Value + 1" (pseudo code) would do the trick. However because not all rows are populated (to allow extra lines for descriptions), this formula does not work.

The "probably" populated Rows start at A5 and the max number is unknown. I looked at this formula and a few others and I always get "Circular Reference Warning" and always returns the result of 0.

```
=OFFSET($A$5,0,0,COUNT($A$5:$A$1048576))
```

Does anyone know of a formula that would allow me to find the previous populated cell's value in Column A? For example, if the last cell was A7 with a 3, it would return 3.

Comment: Please take a look at the accepted answer http://superuser.com/a/923493/243625 as it looks like it might apply here, too.

Comment: I had a look and it sort of looks like what I need. But it seems to require two columns. What would you do if you wanted it all to be in a single column?

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of it far enough. Indeed, it might not be possible apply to here... I also have now only LibreOffice Calc to experiment and it might not do everything as Excel does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MAX` function to find the Max value as

```
=MAX($A$5:A5)
```

to add 1 to the max value

```
=MAX($A$5:A5)+1
```

Note that the first `A5` needs to be absolute as `$A$5` and the second needs to be relative without the dollar sign, so when you copy down it becomes:

```
=MAX($A$5:A6)+1
```

See https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-538396b3-990e-4b44-9d9c-28b4151d7d21

So if you want to populate an ID in column A whenever column B is not blank you can do:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B5),"",MAX($A$5:A5)+1)
```

and copy down.